# Can't run an ELF 32 bits lsb executable intel 80386 because of "zsh: segmentation fault ./file"

Tags: binary, segmentation-fault, launch

[image: error]

[image: ldd]

I have an ELF 32 bits lsb executable intel 80386 but can't run it because of "zsh: segmentation fault ./file".
At the beginning, one library was missing and i download it but then when i launched the file i had this error "zsh: segmentation fault ./file". Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this? Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this?

Yes, people write code that crashes with `SIGSEGV` *all the time*.

What is the provenance of the `./file` executable? Is it something you compiled? If so, use debugger to figure out *where* it crashes.